# how to add click listener to ListFragment blank area

Tags: android, fragment, onclicklistener, android-listfragment, onitemclicklistener

**Update :**

**MyActivity.java**

```
    public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private ListView mListView;
    private ViewGroup mParent;
    private SimpleArrayAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mAdapter = new SimpleArrayAdapter(this);
        mAdapter.add(System.currentTimeMillis() + "");
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mParent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        mParent.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, v.getClass().getName(), 100).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, position + " " + view.getClass().getName(), 100).show();
    }

    class SimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public SimpleArrayAdapter(Context context) {
            this(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        }

        private SimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = new TextView(getContext());
                convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }
            ((TextView) convertView).setText(getItem(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@android:id/content"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:background="@android:color/white"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout >
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.EditListViewDemo"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Question:**
i could use getListView().setOnItemClickListener(listener) to the ListFragment ListView.
but how to add click listener to the blank area?
as shown in the following pic.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add your `ListView` to some `Parent View`, like a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`, and implement `clickListener` for that `Parent`.

That way when you click `ListViewItem`, `setOnItemClickListener(listener)` is called and click elsewhere will call the `parent.setOnClickListener(listener)`.

Comment: thanks @Archie.bpgc. your mean is (ViewGroup)(getListView().getParent()).setOnClickListener()?

Comment: Yeah. You can do that. But make sure your `ListView` has a parent.

Comment: oh, but it does not work .
i add some code in onResume()
ViewGroup listContainer = (ViewGroup) getListView().getParent();
listContainer.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: pls post your layout code. And try setting the click listener using `findViewById(R.id.parent)`

Comment: `setOnClickListener` on the **FrameLayout** `android:id="@android:id/primary"`

Comment: ok, i tried it, but it not work. `EditFragmentActivity.setListener();`, I updated my question. More simple.